# Android migrate Eclipse to Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, export, gradle

I am trying to migrate android project from eclipse, however after clicking Finish button in Export dialog nothing (as in nothing - no changes in UI, no message dialogs, no window closing) happens.

1. Is there some place I could look up for some errors happened? Project error console is empty.
2. How could I generate create gradle file (manually?) myself?

Project is for 2.3.3, API 10

Installed (and reinstalled) APIs:

- Android SDK Tools 22.0.1
- Platform-tools 17
- Build-tools 17
- SDK Platforms: API 17, API 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved by getting rid of all project warnings. @SuppressWarnings'ed warnings are apparently OK too.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me:

1. In Eclipse, Preferences -> Java Built Path ->"Order and Export" tab. Make sure items are selected
2. If you have external Jars, manually copy and paste the jar in the libs folder of the project. (I did this in my Finder)
3. confirm the project launches via Eclipse
4. If it runs, export the project again by "Generate Gradle build files" (confirm overwriting existing files, if any)
5. Open Android
   Studio and re-import the project. Again, confirming overwriting of
   any existing files.
6. Next to the run bottom at the top of the
   screen click on the drop down next to your project name. Click "Edit
   Configurations..." and select "show chooser dialog" if not already
   selected.

Comment: Clarification: found under Project preferences, not Eclipse Preferences.

Comment: This means in Eclipse click on Preferences. There is a 
decimal point ;)

Comment: Didn't help. Played with checkbox combinations, in the end used same setup as I had before trying to export. +1 for "confirm the project launches" - lead to attempt to fix warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Are there any eclipse projects which are not Android ones?

Try only selecting Android projects when exporting to gradle.